# Cant deploy ERC20 token that needs uniswap router on the testnet transaction reverted?

Tags: contract-development, remix, erc-20, uniswap

So its a Token that has tax fee on every transaction. But on deploy it fails do you know why?

- Full source code: `https://pastebin.com/KyJMBie1`
- TXID: `https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x70c2e6d9e5001ea794aec54cc00b0bd7647698eed1ef693e180db3904bc55ab4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers is storage out of gas. For bypass this error use can use the import of libraries.

Try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed 
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";


library Address {
 
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
        // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
        // for accounts without code, i.e. `keccak256('')`
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }
 
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");
 
        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls, avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
 
 
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }
 
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }
 
    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }
 
    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, errorMessage);
    }
 
    function _functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 weiValue, string memory errorMessage) private returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");
 
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{ value: weiValue }(data);
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
 
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
 

contract CronosNaut is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
 
    address payable public marketingAddress = payable(0x3bfC545BdE045e3eef6Ce2e75928946D7C5591f8); // Marketing Address
    address public immutable deadAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
 
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
 
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
 
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
 
    string private _name = "CronosNaut";
    string private _symbol = "CRON";
    uint8 private _decimals = 9;
 
 
    uint256 public _taxFee = 2;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
 
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 2;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
 
    uint256 public marketingDivisor = 2;
 
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 3000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private minimumTokensBeforeSwap = 200000 * 10**6 * 10**9; 
    uint256 private buyBackUpperLimit = 1 * 10**18;
 
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
 
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = false;
    bool public buyBackEnabled = true;
 
 
    event RewardLiquidityProviders(uint256 tokenAmount);
    event BuyBackEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
 
    event SwapETHForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] path
    );
 
    event SwapTokensForETH(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] path
    );
 
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
 
    constructor () {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
 
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
 
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }
 
    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
 
    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
 
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }
 
    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }
 
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }
 
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
 
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
 
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
 
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
 
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }
 
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }
 
    function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }
 
    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }
 
    function minimumTokensBeforeSwapAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
    }
 
    function buyBackUpperLimitAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return buyBackUpperLimit;
    }
 
    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }
 
 
    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }
 
    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }
 
    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
 
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }
 
    function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");
 
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
 
    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(from != owner() && to != owner()) {
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");
        }
 
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        bool overMinimumTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
 
        if (!inSwapAndLiquify && swapAndLiquifyEnabled && to == uniswapV2Pair) {
            if (overMinimumTokenBalance) {
                contractTokenBalance = minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
                swapTokens(contractTokenBalance);    
            }
            uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
            if (buyBackEnabled && balance > uint256(1 * 10**18)) {
 
                if (balance > buyBackUpperLimit)
                    balance = buyBackUpperLimit;
 
                buyBackTokens(balance.div(100));
            }
        }
 
        bool takeFee = true;
 
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
 
        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }
 
    function swapTokens(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
 
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
        swapTokensForEth(contractTokenBalance);
        uint256 transferredBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);
 
        //Send to Marketing address
        transferToAddressETH(marketingAddress, transferredBalance.div(_liquidityFee).mul(marketingDivisor));
 
    }
 
 
    function buyBackTokens(uint256 amount) private lockTheSwap {
        if (amount > 0) {
            swapETHForTokens(amount);
        }
    }
 
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
 
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
 
        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this), // The contract
            block.timestamp
        );
 
        emit SwapTokensForETH(tokenAmount, path);
    }
 
    function swapETHForTokens(uint256 amount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        path[1] = address(this);
 
      // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amount}(
            0, // accept any amount of Tokens
            path,
            deadAddress, // Burn address
            block.timestamp.add(300)
        );
 
        emit SwapETHForTokens(amount, path);
    }
 
    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
 
        // add the liquidity
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
 
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
 
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
 
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }
 
    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
 
    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
 
    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
 
    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
 
    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }
 
    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }
 
    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }
 
    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }
 
    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }
 
    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
 
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }
 
    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
 
    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
 
    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0) return;
 
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
 
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
    }
 
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
    }
 
    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }
 
    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
 
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }
 
    function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _taxFee = taxFee;
    }
 
    function setLiquidityFeePercent(uint256 liquidityFee) external onlyOwner() {
        _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
    }
 
    function setMaxTxAmount(uint256 maxTxAmount) external onlyOwner() {
        _maxTxAmount = maxTxAmount;
    }
 
    function setMarketingDivisor(uint256 divisor) external onlyOwner() {
        marketingDivisor = divisor;
    }
 
    function setNumTokensSellToAddToLiquidity(uint256 _minimumTokensBeforeSwap) external onlyOwner() {
        minimumTokensBeforeSwap = _minimumTokensBeforeSwap;
    }
 
     function setBuybackUpperLimit(uint256 buyBackLimit) external onlyOwner() {
        buyBackUpperLimit = buyBackLimit * 10**18;
    }
 
    function setMarketingAddress(address _marketingAddress) external onlyOwner() {
        marketingAddress = payable(_marketingAddress);
    }
 
    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }
 
    function setBuyBackEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        buyBackEnabled = _enabled;
        emit BuyBackEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }
 
    function prepareForPreSale() external onlyOwner {
        setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(false);
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
        _maxTxAmount = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    }
 
    function afterPreSale() external onlyOwner {
        setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(true);
        _taxFee = 2;
        _liquidityFee = 8;
        _maxTxAmount = 3000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    }
 
    function transferToAddressETH(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
 
     //to recieve ETH from uniswapV2Router when swaping
    receive() external payable {}
}
```

I only import the libraries with `import` keyword (the smart contract code is the same of pastebin).

Comment: I will accept this as it works, so I just want to ask am I 100% there is tax going on?

Comment: There should be 6% fee but there is only 4% https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1e5d4584271589a27502b86c7d4cdc62f095ff4cce379c532c96ff56af41ac2d

Comment: So I change it to goes to marketing addres